# How to *Add To Panel* in 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, usability

In older distros, there is the feature: right-click the top-bar > Add To Panel. But not anymore in Ubuntu 16.04?
I want to create a application icon-shortcut to the application bar. 
I want to use the default settings in the latest Ubuntu. 
I would like to add just a Matlab.desktop icon to the panel.

Comment: I guess you mean a feature in GNOME 2. It was dropped five years ago. But it's still available in MATE desktop environment (a fork of GNOME 2).

Comment: @user300458 Yes. I want to use the defaults in the distro. I just want to add Matlab.desktop icon to the panel and I am wondering where it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Open the application you want to create the shortcut for.

2) Right-click the icon that shows up on the launcher

3) Select "Lock to launcher"
[image]

Comment: Can this method remember options in starting the application? Etc `matlab -softwareopengl`.

Comment: @Masi - I'm not sure if it does or not.

Comment: @Masi you need to create a .desktop file for your application: http://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop

Comment: @JorgeCastro That is not possible in 16.04.

Comment: The correct answer to the question: it is not supported by the default tools as pointed out by *user300458*. I accept this answer to get something accepted.